# document.getElementById().value truncating the seconds if it is 0

Tags: javascript, truncation

I'm a javascript newbie and I'm having a bit of trouble with the following:

```js
function log_time() {
    let time = document.getElementById("time").value;
    console.log(time);
}
```

```html
<input class="input-field" type="time" id="time" onchange="log_time()" step="1">
```

The format of the value is as follows HH:MM:SS however when the seconds are 00, it gets truncated off completely and the resulting time variable becomes HH:MM.

Is there a way to prevent the seconds from being truncated or a check to format the value if the seconds are being truncated?

Comment: There's not enough context to verify or explain what you're describing. If it's a simple text input field, that behavior would not happen.

Comment: Please show all code relevant to the question (in this case, we need to know the HTML of the element with the id "time") as a [mre]. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to create a runnable example here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've added the HTML of the element. Does this suffice?

Comment: Well an expression of time, HH:MM, is exactly the same as HH:MM:00. If you need the zeros, you can always add them in your own code.

Comment: Well the problem is that the field is user input and so how can I check if it's 00 and when it is 00 how would I add them into the code?

Comment: @Jkim045 i cannot reproduce this behaviour, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
const timeElement = document.getElementById("time")

timeElement.addEventListener('change', (e => {
  // extract e.target.value as timeVal with default value "00:00:00"
  const {target: {value: timeVal = "00:00:00"} = {}} = e || {};

  // extract hours, minutes, seconds from the split array.
  const timeValArray = timeVal.split(":");
  const [hours, minutes, seconds = "00"] = timeValArray;

  console.log("hours: ", hours)
  console.log("minutes: ", minutes)
  console.log("seconds: ", seconds)
}
));
```

Output:

```
hours:  17
minutes:  13
seconds:  00
```

Comment: `const {target: {value: timeVal = "00:00:00"} = {}} = e || {};` is shorthand for `const timeVal = e.target.value || "00:00:00";` but also gives defaults values in case e or target are undefined.